# Excel VBA - text files to separate worksheets: Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, loops

This Code [(Source)](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3231-excel-import-multiple-text-files-to-multiple-sheets.html) serves to take multiple text files, all in the same folder, and make a separate worksheet out of each one.  It works for one file, but when it's time to execute on a second file, I get the error message in the title.

I believe all variables are set and I have tried setting variables in the loop, along with moving the incrementor around, and changing `xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy` to `xTempWb.Sheets(1).Add`.  I have also consulted a number of Stack Overflow questions and the MSDN documentation.

It jumps to the error handler at the line: `xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy`

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    'update by ExtendOffice 20151015
        Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim xWb As Workbook
        Dim xTempWb As Workbook
        Dim xDelimiter As String
        Dim xScreen As Boolean
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        xDelimiter = "|"
        xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Kutools for Excel",, True)
        If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
            MsgBox "No files were selected", . "KuTools for Excel"
            GoTo ExitHandler
        End If
        I = 1
        Set xTembWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
        Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        xTempWb.Close False
        xWb.Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType = xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, SemiColon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
            Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
        Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
            I = I + 1
            Set xTembWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilestoOpen(I))
            With xWb
                xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                .Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
                Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
                Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                Other:=True, OtherChar:=xDelimiter
            End With
        Loop
    ExitHandler:
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
        Set xWb = Nothing
        Set xTempWb = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    ErrHandler
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "KuTools For Excel"
        Resume ExitHandler
    End Sub



    End Sub
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There looks to be several issues with the code above and some unncessary lines. After Getting `xFilesTopOpen` adjust your code to below.

Please also notice there was a place where you misspelled `xTempWb` as `xTembWB`. Using `Option Explicit` above your code will help ensure all variables are named as needed.

```
Set xWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim wbCounter as Integer

For wbCounter = LBound(xFilesToOpen) to UBound(xFilesToOpen)

    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))

    xTembWb.Sheets(1).Copy xWB.Worksheets(xWB.Worksheets.Count)

    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Activesheet

     ws.Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType = xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, SemiColon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
            Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"

    xTempWb.Close False

Next
```

Comment: even this will fail. :) the code is alright its just a typing mistake. Classic case of not using `Option Explicit`

Comment: I thought that looked funny when I copied it from above, but didn't bother checking his variable name. I'm leaving my code up (with that edit) because its a whole lot simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

> `Option Explicit`

---

You have declared `Dim xTempWb As Workbook`
and you are setting your text files to `Set xTembWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))` and then trying to use `xTempWb` once again.

That's the issue.